# android dropbox api - app key confusion

Tags: android, api, dropbox

On my android application I use the dropbox API. I hardcode the app key and secret. But to authenticate I need to log in using the dropbox account.

But whats the point of using a app key and secret if you have to enter a username and password.

Also what if you would like other people to be able to upload to your dropbox without using the accounts username and password. Can they use the app key and secret to just upload to the account without entering the accounts username/password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are a bit confused with what are app key/secret used to do. In briefly, a pair of app key/secret is used to identify an app. Is it a valid app? Is it authorized by user? And is it out of API call limit/throttling? Therefore,  only with key/secret, app has no right to access an unauthorized user's private data. I'm sorry but I have to say allowing people upload data to your own cloud is not a good idea. At least, dropbox is not for that purpose. Instead, why not try some other cloud storage service, like Amazon S3?